# SQL How to Bring two results with two differents conditions on two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have this SQL Query

```
SELECT N2 as DOORS, N2 as WINDOWS
   FROM DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB
        WHERE numero=45
        AND CODEITEM='D' OR CODEITEM='W'
```

Right now It brings me 2 columns (DOORS, WINDOWS) with the same results.

What I really want is to bring on the DOORS column only the ITEMS with Code 'D' and on the WINDOWS column only the ITEMS with Code 'W'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @Akina Thanks, I edited already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems want aggregation :

```
SELECT numero, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODEITEM = 'D' THEN N2 END) AS DOORS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODEITEM = 'W' THEN N2 END) AS WINDOWS
FROM DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB
WHERE numero = 45 AND CODEITEM IN ('D', 'W')
GROUP BY numero;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You were the final solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CASE on select

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN codeitem = 'D' THEN N2 ELSE NULL END) AS DOORS, 
  (CASE WHEN codeitem = 'W' THEN N2 ELSE NULL END) AS WINDOWS
FROM DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB
WHERE numero = 45 AND codeitem IN ('D', 'W')
```

Comment: You'll obtain 2 records.

Comment: Yes, you might get multiple records, depends on your data

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

Aggregation function used for the result shown in the same row.

```
SELECT numero, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODEITEM = 'D' THEN CODEITEM ELSE '' END ) AS DOORS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODEITEM = 'W' THEN CODEITEM ELSE '' END) AS WINDOWS
FROM DISTINTAB
WHERE numero = 45 AND CODEITEM IN ('D', 'W')
GROUP BY numero;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general (when `(numero, codeitem)` is not defined as unique):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT n2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codeitem ORDER BY NULL) rn
FROM DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB
WHERE numero=45
  AND codeitem IN ('D', 'W')
)
SELECT t1.n2 as Doors, t2.n2 as Windows
FROM cte t1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte t2 ON t1.rn= t2.rn
```

If the above fields combination is defined as unique then

```
SELECT t1.n2 as Doors, t2.n2 as Windows
FROM DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB t1
FULL OUTER JOIN DATABASE.dbo.DISTINTAB t2 
    ON t1.numero=45
   AND t2.numero=45
   AND t1.codeitem = 'D'
   AND t2.codeitem = 'W'
```